# Make faster 2D canvas with Hardware acceleration and/or WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to improve the speed of my canvas rendering. I often read about hardware acceleration and WebGL, even in 2D (like pixi.js library).

I want to know how to enable them. I've see some tutorial that advise to put some CSS 3D property to canvas, but it seems quite rum...

In fact, I'm not sure that hardware acceleration is not enable by default in every canvas : I don't know, is it ?

So, how can I accelerate my canvas, in developer side (I'm not really interested by user tip in chrome flags or something like that) using WebGL or hardware acceleration ?

Thank you !

Comment: In modern browsers, GPU acceration is enabled by default.  WebGL is simply an alternate context method for drawing on canvas.  WebGL does some things faster and some things slower than context-2d.

Comment: take a look at three.js library. They have implemented a WebGL renderer for accelerated graphics but also a Canvas renderer for non acceleration-capable machines.

Comment: @markE So what about that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635658/how-to-enable-accelerated-hardware-in-javascript-for-canvas?rq=1 Is it outdated ?

Comment: Yes, outdated. Modern browsers enable GPU acceleration by default.